# How to pass click event to another button and trigger popup

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, nuxt.js

I am using this component https://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/popover

I need to pass click event correctly from one button to another and show popup under forwarded button

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/element-ui@2.8.2/lib/index.js"></script>
<div id="app">
<template>
   <el-button @click="$refs.forward.click()">Click to forward</el-button>
  <el-popover
    placement="bottom"
    title="Title"
    width="200"
    trigger="click"
    content="this is content, this is content, this is content">
    <el-button ref="forward" slot="reference">Click to activate</el-button>
  </el-popover>

</template>
</div>
```

I've passed click event via `$refs.forward.click()` but that doesn't trigger popup. Am I missing something?

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dEdENJ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're over thinking it here:

add a new property to `data` called `visible`

```
visible: false
```

And then just mutate that on `click to forward`

```
@click="visible = !visible"
```

Finally, assign that to the `v-model` of the popover:

```
v-model="visible"
```

Done.